# Sql table variable not existing after creation?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm running the following query, but getting the error saying that my table variables don't exist in the last query.  Can anyone see why this is happening and how to correct?

```
DECLARE @customers Table(custName varchar(20), custCode varchar(10) )

INSERT INTO @customers
select distinct  JM.CustLongName, JM.CustomerCode
    From Jobmaster JM
    WHERE StartDate > '20091031' 

DECLARE @Oct Table(custCode varchar(10), PromiseAvg decimal(10,4), ShipAvg decimal(10,4) )

--The following statement is run 12 times with the different months of the year
INSERT INTO @Oct
SELECT  JM.CustomerCode
  , isnull(AVG(Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(startDate, 0), ISNULL(PromiseDate, 0)) As Decimal)),0) As PromiseAvg
  , isnull(AVG(Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(startDate, 0), ISNULL(BOL.ShipDate, 0)) As Decimal)),0) As ShipAvg
from jobitems JI
LEFT JOIN jobmaster JM ON JI.Job_Number = JM.JobNumber
LEFT JOIN dbo.NCL_BOLDetails BD ON JM.JobNumber = BD.JobNumber AND JI.Item_Code = BD.ItemNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.NCL_BOLs BOL ON BD.BOLID = BOL.BOLID
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN '20101001' AND '20101031'    
Group By JM.CustomerCode, JM.CustLongName
Order By JM.CustomerCode

/*....copies removed for brevity.....*/

Select [@customers].custCode, [@customers].custName
  , [@Nov].PromiseAvg, [@Nov].ShipDate
  , [@Dec].PromiseAvg, [@Dec].ShipDate
  , [@Jan].PromiseAvg, [@Jan].ShipDate
  , [@Feb].PromiseAvg, [@Feb].ShipDate
  , [@Mar].PromiseAvg, [@Mar].ShipDate
  , [@Apr].PromiseAvg, [@Apr].ShipDate
  , [@May].PromiseAvg, [@May].ShipDate
  , [@Jun].PromiseAvg, [@Jun].ShipDate
  , [@Jul].PromiseAvg, [@Jul].ShipDate
  , [@Aug].PromiseAvg, [@Aug].ShipDate
  , [@Sep].PromiseAvg, [@Sep].ShipDate
  , [@Oct].PromiseAvg, [@Oct].ShipDate
FROM @customers
LEFT JOIN [@Nov] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Nov].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Dec] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Dec].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Jan] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Jan].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Feb] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Feb].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Mar] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Mar].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Apr] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Apr].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@May] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@May].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Jun] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Jun].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Jul] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Jul].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Aug] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Aug].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Sep] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Sep].custCode
LEFT JOIN [@Oct] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Oct].custCode
```

Comment: Are you running all of this at once or parts of it at a time?

Comment: Its running all at once.  One long file.

Comment: OK, can you show the exact error message?

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
Select c.custCode, c.custName
  , n.PromiseAvg, n.ShipDate
  , d.PromiseAvg, d.ShipDate
  , j.PromiseAvg, j.ShipDate
  , f.PromiseAvg, f.ShipDate
  , m.PromiseAvg, m.ShipDate
  , a.PromiseAvg, a.ShipDate
  , mm.PromiseAvg, mm.ShipDate
  , jj.PromiseAvg, jj.ShipDate
  , jl.PromiseAvg, jl.ShipDate
  , ag.PromiseAvg, ag.ShipDate
  , s.PromiseAvg, s.ShipDate
  , o.PromiseAvg, o.ShipDate
FROM @customers c
LEFT JOIN @Nov n ON  c.custCode = n.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Dec d ON  c.custCode = d.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Jan j ON  c.custCode = j.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Feb f ON  c.custCode = f.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Mar m ON  c.custCode = m.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Apr a ON  c.custCode = a.custCode
LEFT JOIN @May mm ON  c.custCode = mm.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Jun jj ON  c.custCode = jj.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Jul jl ON  c.custCode = jl.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Aug ag ON  c.custCode = ag.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Sep s ON  c.custCode = s.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Oct o ON  c.custCode = o.custCode
```

Comment: Although I'm a bit uncertain about taking advice from a VilliageIdiot, he seems to have become the VillageGenius!  I changed ShipDate to ShipAvg, as that is the column I needed and it worked!

Comment: I have noted this, but as you commented that `/*....copies removed for brevity.....*/` I thought may be this exists and is not shown in question.

Comment: The section before that comment is repeated with the only change being the 3 letter month abbreviation.  Its exactly the same otherwise.  Copy and paste, then find/replace.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out the alias

```
FROM @customers
```

should be

```
FROM @customers [@customers]
```

You will probably need to change `LEFT JOIN [@Nov]` to `LEFT JOIN @Nov [@Nov]` etc. as well unless these are actually permanent tables. So your query needs to look like

```
...
FROM @customers [@customers]
LEFT JOIN @Nov [@Nov] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Nov].custCode
LEFT JOIN @Dec [@Dec] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Dec].custCode
LEFT JOIN @Jan [@Jan] ON  [@customers].custCode = [@Jan].custCode
...
```

Comment: @Maw74656 - You'll need to do it with all the tables in the `join` as well.

Comment: Are you saying that i HAVE to use alias's to reference table variables?

Comment: @MAW74656 Yes. When you table qualify columns from a TV you always need to alias the TV. Bit of a pain!

Comment: I have this changed now, but I'm getting a Line 188: Incorrect syntax near '.'

Comment: I have never had to alias my table variables.

Comment: @Mike - I take it you have never  joined them to anything then! @MAW74656 And did you undo the change you made at Randy's suggestion that gave you that same error?

Comment: @maw74656 - Well you can't have done it right as you should have ended up with conceptually exactly the same thing as the answer you ended up accepting! (The only difference being the names of the aliases)

Comment: Well, I must have missed some detail that TheVilliageIdiot cleared up in his code.  There's no need to place blame, you helped me and I gave you +1, but the idiot had the perfect answer.

Comment: @MAW74656 - Blame was implicitly placed on my answer by you saying that you tried it and got an error message!

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would say you have a GO statement in there somewhere that we cannot see. If so, this would cause all declared variables occurring before to lose scope, and be unavailable after the GO. A semi-colon might have the same effect, but I'm not confident of that.

Comment: @MAW74656 - Ok. One last suggestion. Remove the brackets around @customers in your Select statement.

Comment: using `GO` between statements will render all the variables declared before `GO` inaccessible after it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the column Shipdate defined. A solution might look similar too

```
...
Select c.custCode, c.custName
  , nov.PromiseAvg, nov.ShipDate
  , dec.PromiseAvg, dec.ShipDate
FROM @customers c
LEFT JOIN @Nov nov ON  c.custCode = nov.custCode
LEFT JOIN @Dec dec ON  c.custCode = dec.custCode
```